# New-AzureRMSqlDatabaseImport doesnt accept login programmatically

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database

Im using the below code to import a database from a bacpac file:

```
$importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
   -ServerName $AzureServer `
   -DatabaseName $TRIS5DatabaseName `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "262144000" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey $StorageKey `
   -StorageUri $URI `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "S0" `
   -AdministratorLogin "user" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

The request just returns bad request unless i remove the bottom two lines and enter the the login manually at the prompt:

```
   -AdministratorLogin "user" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "password" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Everything works fine if i remove these two lines and enter manually, but i want this part to be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `'password'` instead of `"password"`, it may work fine.

Per my test, if I use a password includes some characters like `$`, it will return a bad request error.

[image]

Otherwise, it works fine.

[image]

So I suppose there may be some characters in your password that need to be escaped.

After changing `""` to `''`, it works fine.

[image]

Comment: I'll have to try it tomorrow but that's probably it. Thanks